# Can I create C# class object in JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor-webassembly

I'm trying to call function inside class in cs file from JavaScript file like this:

**.cs** file:

```
 public class ReadDataBase
    {
        [Inject]
        public HttpClient Http { get; set; }

        string theState;
        Cities city;

        public async Task<string> GetState(string Name)
        {
            city= await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<Cities>("City/Details/" + Name);
            theState = city.State;
            return theState;
        }
    }
```

in **.js** file I want to do like this:

```
window.onload = function ()
{
var readDataBase = new ReadDataBase();

const state = readDataBase.GetState(cityName);

document.getElementById("state").innerHTML = State;

}
```

This is wrong way but how can I do this?

Comment: Is it MVC or asp.net webforms? Ideally, you can use the jQuery Ajax function that performs asynchronous HTTP requests and gets the data from the server. https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/jquery/jquery-ajax-method

Comment: @AkshayGaonkar Blazor WebAssembly, Thank you!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-dotnet-from-javascript?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Answer (score 1):

You can not share C# and JavaScript code this way. This is simply because those are two different languages and the JavaScript execution environment  doesn't know what to do with it.

It seems like you are using .NET Core, take a look at the MVC model and [the basics of a REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio). This enables you to expose your database as JSON data. When this is working you can use JavaScript to make a HTTP request to you REST API and receive the data.

Comment: Thank you! I'll see it.